# Proving trigonometric identity $1+\cot x\tan y=\frac{\sin(x+y)}{\sin x\cos y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

$$1+\cot x\tan y=\frac{\sin(x+y)}{\sin x\cos y}$$

I have worked through most of this question, and I believe I am so close to finding the answer, but I have run into some issues where I am not sure about what to do next.

This is what I did:
$LS$C
$\sin^2x + \cos^2x+1/\tan x(\sin y/\cos y)$
$=\sin^2x+\cos^2x+ 1/\sin x/\cos x(\sin y/\cos y)$

After this point, I am not certain what to do.  If someone could please help me, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). The formulas in "what I did" are hard to read. I reformatted the identity.

Comment: @pizza Okay! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I would work with the right-hand side. We have $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y$ and now it's almost over.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas Okay, well I have gone ahead and tried out your method and it does appear to be a lot easier.  I didn't think of the sin(a+b) identity.  However how do I go from this to 1+cotxtany? Since both sides must equal eachother?

Comment: We quickly get to $\frac{\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y}{\sin x\cos y}$. Divide. We get $1+\frac{\cos x\sin y}{\sin x\cos y}$. But $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=\cot x$ and $\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}=\tan y$, and we are finished.

Answer (score 3):

$$1+\cot x\tan y=1+\frac{\cos x\sin y}{\sin x\cos y}=\frac{\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y}{\sin x\cos y}$$

$\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y=\sin(x+y)$

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee Hang on, would you be able to explain the conversion that took place to get from $cosxsiny to $$frac\{cosxsiny/sinxcosy}$?

Comment: please excuse me, I am still getting used to using the notations on this site

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different method.
$$1+\cot x\tan y = 1+\frac{\cos x \sin y}{\sin x \cos y}$$
Taking the LCM you are done.

Answer (score 2):

When I'm really stuck with proving an identity of the form
$$f(x,y)=g(x,y)$$
I multiply the LHS by $\frac{g(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$
$$
f(x,y)=f(x,y)\cdot\frac{g(x,y)}{g(x,y)}=\bigg(\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}\bigg)g(x,y)
$$
now it's just a matter of showing that
$$\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)} = 1$$
which in the case of the problem that you presented, involves showing that
$$\frac{(\sin x \cos y)(1+\cot x\tan y)}{\sin (x+y)}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Checkout the photo below for solution. Sorry if it's not clear to view